# How can I locate the device that log in my gmail account?

Tags: passwords, forensics, gmail

My company Gmail was logged into by someone else and sent out unhealthy messages to people in my company.

I looked back to my login history and found a phone device login which is not mine.

Can I locate the location of the device user? Or is there any way I can track that person down? Because I know someone in my company did that.

Comment: It sounds like you need to immediately change your password and enable 2FA.  If you have an Android phone you can get Google Authenticator" from the play store, so that any login from unknown devices will prompt you on the phone to click Yes or No to that login.

Comment: your Google apps admin will know more - please contact your admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [Google Accouts](http://accounts.google.com) and login.

In first column, Sign-in & security, click on **Device activity & notifications**. There you will see Recently used devices. You can **review devices**, where you can click on one to show device model, OS, browser and location used.

Or, in **Recent security events** under Device activity you can find latest (untrusted) devices logged in to your account, showing their IPs and exact locations.

I recommend contacting your company's admin and setting up two **2-Step Verification** (a security code required by login will be sent to your phone number - or way better in terms of security - to your Google app)

Answer (score 2):

My answer:  Use gmail's "last account activity" function to see information on utilization of your account.

It is explained here:  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938?hl=en

Here is an excerpt:

> You can see the last 10 IP addresses and approximate locations  that
>   accessed your Gmail account.
>
> If you got a warning about suspicious activity in your account, you
>   might also see up to 3 additional IP addresses that have been labeled
>   as suspicious.
>
> There are a few reasons you may see multiple IP addresses or locations
>   in your activity:
>
> If you use POP or IMAP to read your mail on other services, like Apple
>   Mail or Microsoft Outlook, this location information will be included,
>   too.
>
> If you use Mail Fetcher, a Google IP will show up because your
>   messages are being fetched through a Google server.
>
> If you use Gmail on a phone or tablet, your Internet service or mobile
>   carrier's location may show up. This may be a location far from where
>   you are. As long as the name of the carrier matches yours, this isn't
>   unusual.

While on this topic, it is highly suggested you use 2FA security on gmail to prevent this from happening.  I use Google Authenticator on my Android phone so I can click Yes or No to any unknown logins.

Answer (score 0):

Google would send you an email with some info like the OS and public ip of the device. But that just means that device was used connected to some router. You cant know for sure if that ip ( dynamically assigned) if the person's actual ip or some starbucks ip. Better off making sure your password is strong. you can check which devices are currently logged in as your account by looking in your google security preferences.

Comment: I already changed password.  I just want to find out who is the rat! What else can I do beside knowing which IP address? Because IP address cannot give mich information.

Comment: @AnhTai im sorry to say you have next to zero chance finding the person.

Comment: edit last comment: theres nothing else you can do to find the person.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is logged onto your google account on a phone, Google "find my device" from there you can see every device that's logged onto your Google account track their location. I do not know if this person logged into your Google account or just your email. (same email and password for both) but its worth a try.